# Number of solutions of the equation: $\sin^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}x^2=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

> What is the number of solutions of the equation: $\sin^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}x^2=\frac{\pi}{2}$?
>
> 1. None
> 2. Greater than or equal to 1
> 3. Less than or equal to 1
> 4. Equal to 2

It is a *single-option-correct* MCQ. I tried using substitution, but that leads to a very lengthy expression that I cannot solve. Can anyone show me the way?

Comment: This is automatically satisfied if and only if $x=x^2$.

Comment: But, isn't $2$ greater than or equal to $1$?

Comment: @Hetebrij Yes, but only one answer is accepted... so, the closest one is the right one. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sin^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}x^2=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$\cos^{-1}x^2=\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin^{-1}x=\cos^{-1}x$$
$$\cos^{-1}x^2=\cos^{-1}x$$

This implies, that for principal value of the argument,
$$x^2=x$$
$$x(x-1)=0$$

The equation hence has $2$ roots.

The correct answer to the MCQ should be $\color{red}{\text{OPTION (D)}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me... This was an easy question.

We know,
$$
\sin^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}y=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
iff $x=y$

Therefore, in my question,
$$x = x^2$$
$$or,x^2-x=0$$
$$or,x(x-1)=0$$
i.e. $x=1$ or $0$
The correct option is D.
Thank you [Paul](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680306/number-of-solutions-of-the-equation-sin-1x-cos-1x2-frac-pi2#comment3428984_1680306) and [SchrodingersCat](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1680312/203386)